# Case in where mysql not working

Tags: mysql, database

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as tdb 
FROM (`v_ledger_details`) 
WHERE `debit_credit` = 'DB' 
AND `CASE` WHEN transaction_type_id IN(4,5) 
           THEN billDate < "2016-06-01" 
           ELSE postingDate < "2016-06-01" 
     END 
AND accountId = '944'
```

what is worong with the above query. i need the case  claues in where but that query give me error.

Comment: What exactly is the error you are getting? can u post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use `case` in a `where` clause. Normally only use it in `select` clauses. And then don't backtick the `case` keyword

```
SELECT SUM(amount) as tdb 
FROM v_ledger_details
WHERE `debit_credit` = 'DB' 
AND accountId = '944'
AND 
(
    (transaction_type_id IN (4,5) and billDate < '2016-06-01') OR
    (transaction_type_id NOT IN (4,5) AND postingDate < '2016-06-01')
)
```